# Processing only the current directory with find/prune

Tags: bash, find

I've been reading up on find's -prune action. One common task I do is to process only the files of a directory, ignoring all directories.

Prune, from what I've learned, is great for ignoring directories if you know their names (or wildcards matching their names). But what if you don't know their names (or a pattern that matches files as well as directories)?

I found that -maxdepth achieves what I'm trying to do. I'm just wondering what the equivalent -prune approach might be.

For example, say I want to process all the files of my home directory, but not recurse into any subdirectory. Let's say my directory structure and files look like this (directories ending in '/'):

~/tmpData.dat
~/.bashrc
~/.vimrc
~/.Xdefaults
~/tmp/
~/tmp/.bashrc
~/bkups/.bashrc
~/bkups/.vimrc
~/bkups/.Xdefaults
~/bkups/tmpData.dat

.. what would be the correct find/prune command?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found my own solution. I simply specify pattern(s) that match everything in my
home directory ('~/*' for example). But in order to include all my dot files (.bashrc,
etc.), I have to use *two* patterns; one for non-dotted filenames and one for the files
starting with dots:

```
find ~/* ~/.* -type d -prune -o -type f -print
```